# Popup Window.Opener Redirected or Closed

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am opening a window using `window.open` and calling `window.opener.SomeFunction()`.

If I click some link on opener and later call `window.opener.SomeFunction()`, it says it does not exist as it was redirected. Is there a way to detect it before calling the function?

Tried this but it doesn't work

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed){
    window.opener.SomeFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the function before calling it,

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed && window.opener.SomeFunction){
window.opener.SomeFunction();
}
```

The reason your check of `opener` doesnt work is because, the `opener` is not closed or inactive it just navigated to a page which doesnt contain `SomeFunction`. Thats why you need to add a check for the existence of `SomeFunction` as well.