# Calling function on opener window

Tags: javascript

The child lost its parent!!

I have a parent window, when somebody clicks on an image a JS popup opens and displays the photo and its information.

To close the popup/child window, and to flash an element on my parent/opener window, I have been using this function:

```
function closeWindow() {
    var currentID = document.getElementById('currentID').value;
    window.opener.flashElement(currentID);
    window.close(); 
}
```

My problem is this doesn't work if my users navigate away from the page that the popup originally opened. For example, in the popup window, there are next and previous buttons to scroll through the individual photos in that set of results, which reloads the page with a new querystring value.

If my user scrolls (reloads page) less than 7 times it's okay but if they scroll more than that, the `window.opener` function does not work, and because of that, the `window.close` function doesn't either!

I could probably rebuild the page so the data comes via an AJAX call, rather than reloading the page, but that's a lot of work I could do without.

Any ideas?

Comment: When is the `closeWindow()` function being called? When the user clicks a "close" button or something similar? And just to be totally clear, `closeWindow()` is in the child window, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup Window.Opener Redirected or Closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872721/popup-window-opener-redirected-or-closed)

Comment: @JackieChiles yes closeWindow() is called when the users clicks a close button and the closeWindow() is in the child window. As I say, it works fine if the user doesn't reload the popup more than 7-8 times.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - yes similar question, the title of the question is not obvious though. He's also asking how to fix the problem, I'm trying to find out why the problem is happening..

Comment: People still use popup windows in almost-2012? :o

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Yes, both Twitter and Facebook still use popup windows. Check Twitter developer pages. They can't be that bad :)

Comment: and.. Google Fonts use popup windows. 3 big names still use them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is that

```
window.opener.flashElement(currentID);
```

is throwing an error, or the function does not exist.  Most likely the element with the value of currentID does not exist on the page.  Try catching the error.

```
function closeWindow() {
    var currentID = document.getElementById('currentID').value;
    try {
        window.opener.flashElement(currentID);
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.description || err) //or console.log or however you debug
    }
    window.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Right that helped quite a lot actually. I found out that the currentID value was empty, so it was causing an error within the function on the parent page. But this still doesn't explain why the currentID is missing in the 1st place. It's a hidden text-field populated by ASP with photoID. If the photoID wasn't present the page wouldn't load! Strange!!