# vue.js2 execute method on main window from popup

Tags: vue.js, popup

in the `settings.vue` page there's a method that opens a popup:

```
...
this.logWindow= window.open(this.url,'login',options);
...
```

and another that should process the value returned from popup:

```
  setData(d)
  {
    console.log('logged: ' + d);
    ....
  }
```

when login process is over, I need to pass the result to the main window, calling a method (or passing value):
to do this, in the popup I put the following code:

```
<script>
const logged='true';
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => { 
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        window.opener.setData(logged);
    }
});
</script>
```

but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.opener.setData is not a function
```

can suggest the path for a successful solution?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see when log `window.opener`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611278/calling-function-on-opener-window/8611611) help?

Comment: Hi!
I see an object: `Window {0: global, 1: global, window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
0: global {window: global, self: global, location: {…}, closed: false, frames: global, …}
1: global {window: global, self: global, location: {…}, closed: false, frames: global, …}
Iframe: ƒ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
IframeBase: ƒ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,k)
IframeProxy: ƒ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
IframeWindow: ƒ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
Prism: {manual: undefined, disableWorkerMessageHandler: undefined, util: {…}, languages: {…}, plugins: {…}, …}`